# How to swap lines in a text file?

Tags: c++, text, file-io, swap

I have a text file; let's say the text file has 10 lines.
I want to swap between line 3 and line 6.

How can I do it? Also, I can't create any temporary file for the swap.

Comment: To be safe, you need a temp file...

Comment: If you can't create a temp file, why not load all into array of lines? and then swap in program, rewrite the file.

Comment: i edited my question

Comment: I reverted the latest edit because it invalidated existing answers. If you want to add restrictions on answers, you better ask a different question. This will increase the chance of you getting a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**WARNING: This will overwrite your original file!!!**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    ifstream in("in.txt");
    if (in.is_open())
    {
        std::vector<std::string> content;
        for (std::string line; std::getline(in, line); )
        {
            content.push_back(line);
        }
        in.close();
        std::iter_swap(content.begin() + 2, content.begin() + 5);

        ofstream out("in.txt");
        if (out.is_open()) {
            for (auto i : content)
            {
                out << i << std::endl;
            }
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by nothing? Like it or not, you have to story something anyway.

Answer (score 1):

For this solution to work correctly, the lines cannot contain a single whitespace, as that would be used as a delimiter.

```
const std::string file_name = "data.txt";

// read file into array
std::ifstream ifs{ file_name };
if (!ifs.is_open())
    return -1; // or some other error handling
std::vector<std::string> file;
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(ifs), std::istream_iterator<std::string>(), std::back_inserter(file));
ifs.close();

// now you can swap
std::swap(file[2], file[5]);

// load new array into file
std::ofstream ofs{ file_name, std::ios_base::trunc };
if (!ofs.is_open())
    return -1; // or some other error handling
std::copy(file.begin(), file.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(ofs, "\n"));
```

Comment: While it's cool that with C++17 we can use a functional style like this, it's not so good for error handling. Using functional style we can't make the stream throw exceptions and we can't differentiate between *open* and *read* errors (both set failbit). This can be done better using local stream variables.

Comment: @zett42 I don't understand. The file exists, due to the first condition. And there can't be any read errors I think, because every byte can be interpreted as a character. So I don't see why using the local stream variables is an advantage, no errors can be set so why use them?

Comment: _The file exists, due to the first condition_ ... you can't be sure of that. First it's a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), that means something could happen between the call to `is_regular_file()` and the construction of the `ifstream` that invalidates the 1st check. In addition, checking the type of a file is not the same as opening it. You may successfully check the type, but fail to open it because of missing permissions.

Comment: @zett42 You're right, I understand now :) Thanks a lot, it is fixed now.